# Strange water pressure problem

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

I have a water pressure problem (city line).  In our kitchen, which is the first physical stop (not counting washing machine) for hot water, the hot water flow pressure seems fine, but the cold water pressure is weak.  I'd guess about 25% of the hot water pressure.  Yet in the first bathroom (next in the chain), it's the opposite, but to a greater extreme.  The cold water gushes just fine, but the hot water is more a trickle in comparison, maybe 15% of the cold water pressure.  Not only that, but running the water in the bathroom or the washing machine causes the kitchen sink faucet to go from a drip to a steady stream leak for the duration of the use of water.

Is this something that the city needs to fix, since I do pay a water bill, or is it up to us as homeowners to hire a plumber or someone else to figure out what is going on and fix it?  This has been an on-going problem for years, I'm guilty of putting-off addressing it.

Comment: You need a plumber, what's in your house is up to you to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a possibility that the valve may not be open completely, or a small debris plug. Make sure the valves under the sink are open completely. If no change, turn them off, disconnect them and look for an online water filter and make sure it is clean. If no filter, or it is clean, then check the faucet valve. Again disassemble the valve (handle assembly) and look for debris. 1 or both of these could be your issue. Do the same on the other faucet. If after these checks and cleanings, thing don't improve, then your shut off valve under the sink could be blocked with debris. Same check applies here except you need to make sure the water is shut off to the house first. Make sure all your joints you disconnect are tightened completely before restoring water.